# How to manage multiple assets in a smart contract?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

I am creating a Javascript smart contract using the ibp extension.
ibp prompts me to enter the name of the asset that will be managed by the smart contract and creates functions for CRUD operation on that asset. I need to manage several assets in my use case. Should I create a separate smart contract? Or should I just add my new asset to the same contact?

I ask this question because I want to perform efficient queries on the assets. And find them by their key.

Comment: The single asset creation is purely to get you started with an example, you can add more assets to your contract implementation if you wish, it really depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way would be to create a separate Assets file and create all your asset definitions in there.